# Oracle Apex passing item value

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Item select list `Workspace` value (a,b,c) in page 1

I am selecting some value ex:'a' in item page 1 and stored that in table.

Now I want to display the selected value in page 1 to should display as default item value of another item in another page 2 as default value.

Is this is possible please let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for an item can be taken from another item by setting the **Default Type** to **PL/SQL Expression**. You can refer to another item on the page using bind variable syntax, e.g. `:P2_WORKSPACE`.

In the navigation from page 1 to page 2, you would need to copy `P1_WORKSPACE` into `P2_WORKSPACE` (this is preferable to referring directly to the page 1 item).